# ClickHouse MV is not working perfectly as i need

Tags: database-design, schema, clickhouse

I’m new to ClickHouse and having an issue with MV. I have a record table which is the data source. I’m inserting all the data here. Then created another table called adv_general_report using mv_adv_general_report materialized view.

This is my [schema](https://pastebin.com/RekgUnyB).

[Records table data](https://ufile.io/gzcp25gi).

The odd part is after inserting the data to record table, the sum of impression is perfectly adding to both adv_general_report and mv_adv_general_report materialized view but views and clicks are always showing zero.

You can see running this query. That showing amount of view

```
SELECT sum(views) as views from records;
```

[image]

But if you run this

```
select sum(views) as views from adv_general_report;
```

[image]

It’s 0 . also the select query used for a materialized view is showing the sum of view perfectly. Any idea why?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @armitage I didn't actually post an image of code. I just showed the output of it :/

Comment: The code was already in text format to help people copy.

Comment: instead of adding images of output, create a markdown-table, as shown in [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- it doesn't need to apply any aggregation functions to columns from sorting key - *campaign_id, adgroup_id, ads_id, MINUTE*

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adv_general_report (
    campaign_id Int32, /* <<--- */
    adgroup_id Int32,
    ads_id Int32,
    MINUTE Int32,

    TIME SimpleAggregateFunction(any,DateTime) DEFAULT now(),
    /* .. */
    advertiser_cost SimpleAggregateFunction(SUM,Float64) DEFAULT 0.00
)
engine = AggregatingMergeTree
    PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(TIME)
    ORDER BY (MINUTE,ads_id,campaign_id,adgroup_id)
    PRIMARY KEY (MINUTE,ads_id,campaign_id,adgroup_id)
    SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_adv_general_report TO adv_general_report
    AS SELECT
          campaign_id, /* <<--- */
          adgroup_id,
          ads_id,
          MINUTE,

          any(TIME) AS TIME,
          /* .. */
          SUM(advertiser_cost) AS advertiser_cost
        FROM records
        WHERE isNotNull(records.campaign_id)
        GROUP BY campaign_id, adgroup_id, ads_id, MINUTE;
```

- need to pass *GROUP BY* clause to select data

```sql
select campaign_id, sum(views) as views 
from adv_general_report
group by campaign_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you cleared my confusion. that was a silly mistake from me.